# Is $S=\{p\in \mathbb{Z}[x] | p(0)\in 3\mathbb{Z}\}$ principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know how to prove that $S$ is an ideal, but I don't know how to check whether is $S=\langle p\rangle,$ where $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x].$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $3\in S$ and $x\in S$.$\;$Do they have a common factor other than $\pm 1$?

Comment: No, their common factor is 1 (-1), so $S$ is not a principal. Thank you!